# Codeigniter Passing Search Data in a Template Modal

Tags: php, codeigniter, search

I'm trying to implement a search function to my website. I'm facing an error of can't passing data via templating. I get a blank page in search query even i try to search with a keyword which website contains. My default controller is page.

main layout view :

```
<?php $this->load->view('templates/' .$subview); ?>
```

page controller. I can't pass data from _search i think.

```
public function index() {
    // Fetch the page template
    $this->data['page'] = $this->page_m->get_by(array('slug' => (string) $this->uri->segment(1 , 'homepage')), TRUE); 
    count($this->data['page']) OR show_404(current_url());

    // Fetch the page data
    $method = '_' . $this->data['page']->template;
    if (method_exists($this, $method)) {
        $this->$method();
    }
    else {
        log_message('error', 'Could not load template ' . $method .' in file ' . __FILE__ . ' at line ' . __LINE__);
        show_error('Fail : ' . $method);
    }
    // Load the view

    $this->data['subview'] = $this->data['page']->template;
    $this->load->view('_main_layout', $this->data);
}
private function _page(){ // standart page template, just showing for how i do
    $this->load->model('page_m');
    $this->data['pages'] = $this->page_m->get();
}

private function _search(){
    $this->load->model('search_m'); // problem is here i think
}
```

Search controller, keyword function :

```
 function keyword()
{
    $keyword = $this->input->post('keyword');
    $this->data['results'] = $this->search_m->search($keyword);
    $this->data['subview'] = 'search';
    $this->load->view('_main_layout',$this->data);
}
```

Search Model:

```
 function search($keyword)
 {
    $this->db->like('body',$keyword);
    return parent::get();
 }
```

Search View:

```
  <?php if (count($results)): foreach ($results as $result): ?>
    <?php echo $result->title; ?>
    <?php echo $result->body; ?>
  <?php endforeach; endif; ?>
```

This gives, undefined variable error. If edit that search view code this :

```
<?php if(isset($results)): ?>
<?php if (count($results)): foreach ($results as $result): ?>
<?php echo $result->title; ?>
<?php echo $result->body; ?>
<?php endforeach; endif; endif; ?>
```

I get a blank page after this search query, which means i think i can't get the results data.
What i'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you loading the model, but not calling the function. Am I looking past something?

Your search controller doesn't look like it is inheriting from the default controller, is it? You're cutting out all the code we need to see

Comment: i'm inheriting the default controller and default model and so on. i just didn't write them here, as the other functions of the site are working. i thought i'm passing the data in search controller but not working i think.

Comment: make your functions public

Comment: No problem. For other to understand, http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php  "Class members declared public can be accessed everywhere. Members declared protected can be accessed only within the class itself and by inherited and parent classes. Members declared as private may only be accessed by the class that defines the member. "